# Mostrar usuarios que no tienen un departamento

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Quiero mostrar los nombres de las personas que no tienen un `departamento`

Los datos son:

```
+----+---------+----------------+    +----+--------------------+
| id | Nombre  | idDepartamento |    | id | NombreDepartamento |
+----+---------+----------------+    +----+--------------------+
| 44 | Daniel  |        1       |    | 1  |    Desarrollo      |
+----+---------+----------------+    +----+--------------------+
| 45 | Manuel  |        0       |    | 2  |   Contabilidad     |
+----+---------+----------------+    +----+--------------------+
| 47 |  Juan   |        0       |
+----+---------+----------------+
| 49 | Alfonso |        0       |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

Los quiero mostrar en un `select` de [html](/questions/tagged/html) usando [razor](/questions/tagged/razor) en [asp.net-mvc-5](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-5)

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<select class="form-control" name="UsuarioSelect" multiple>
  @{foreach (var departamento in Model.Departamentos)
  {
    <optgroup label="@departamento.Departamento"></optgroup>
    foreach (var empleado in Model.Empleados)
    {
      if (empleado.IdDepartamento == departamento.id)
      {
        <option value="@empleado.id">@empleado.Nombre</option>
      }
    }
  }}
</select>
```

Pero no tengo idea de como mostrar los usuarios que no tienen un departamento.

**¿Qué necesito agregar en mi código para que se muestren?**

Lo que quiero lograr es algo como esto:

```js
$('select').select2({
  width: '50%'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="Select2" multiple>
  <optgroup label='Desarrollo'></optgroup>
  <option value='44'>Daniel</option>
  <optgroup label='Contabilidad'></optgroup>
  <optgroup label='Sin Departaento'></optgroup>
  <option value='45'>Juan</option>
  <option value='47'>Manuel</option>
  <option value='49'>Alfonso</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero ¿como es que pones las tabla como ASCII?

Comment: Creo que si, que software usas para poder copiar así las tablas?, es mera curiosidad mía :-$, discúlpame si no tiene que ver con tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta lo siguiente usando `Linq` en tu en tu razor:

```
<select class="form-control" name="UsuarioSelect" multiple>
  <optgroup label="Sin Departamento"></optgroup>
  @foreach (var empleado in Model.Empleados.Where(i=>i.IdDepartamento == 0))
  {    
    <option value="@empleado.id">@empleado.Nombre</option>
  }

  @{foreach (var departamento in Model.Departamentos)
  {
    <optgroup label="@departamento.Departamento"></optgroup>
    foreach (var empleado in Model.Empleados.Where(i=>i.IdDepartamento == departamento.id))
    {
       <option value="@empleado.id">@empleado.Nombre</option>         
    }
  }
</select>
```

Comment: Desconozco `Linq` podrías explicarme que hace exactamente `Model.Empleados.Where(i=>i.IdDepartamento == departamento.id)`, si yo tuviera un `null` en `idDepartamento` como quedaría el  `Linq`

Comment: Del listado de empleados que tengas dentro del modelo, Linq te permite filtrar (Como un sentencia SQL) únicamente los empleados que en su columna IdDepartamento posean el id del departamento que actualmente estas recorriendo con el foreach.

Comment: que cambiaría si aparte de validar `0` quiero también validar que sea `null`  principal hacer esto `(idDepartamento == 0 || idDepartamento == null)` como se haría en `Linq`

Comment: Si, seria mas o menos como lo estas planteando: Model.Empleados.Where(i=>i.IdDepartamento == 0 || i.IdDepartamento == null).